Layers effect on total energy
I am using DFT (GGA).
I was told I should reduce the thickness of a slab to reduce the computation time but at the same time, I had to see if that was okay.
I submitted my reduced-thickness slab and got different energy from the original slab. Does that mean the effects of asymmetry between the surface and the bottom of the slab were not canceled in the bulk?
The surface I submitted is functionalized with a molecule and I did not run the calculation for the energy of the clean reduced-thickness slab.
PS: I am a beginner.

+1. Welcome to our community.

+1 but I have just limited your post to 1 question, to comply with our 1 question/post policy.
